# TypeError: __init__() missing 3 required positional arguments in class

Tags: python, init

I'm practicing python and I get this error, and I keep getting missing 3 positional requirements, here is the code:

```
shape = input('Enter shape to calculate, must be "SQUARE", "TRIANGLE", "RECTANGLE", "TRAPEZOID":')


class Calc():
#    if shape == 'TRAPEZOID': base2 = int(input('Enter second base size:'))

    def __init__(self):
        self.base = int(input('Enter base:'))
        self.height = int(input('Enter height:')


class Trapezoid(Calc):

     def __init__(self, height, base, base2):
         super().__init__(height, base)
         self.base2 = int(input("Enter second base for Trapezoid:"))

     def getArea(self):
         return (self.base + self.base2) * self.height / 2


if shape == 'SQUARE':
    Square = Square()
    print ("Square Area is" , Square.getArea())
if shape == 'TRIANGLE':
    Triangle = Triangle()
    print ("Triangle Area is" , Triangle.getArea())
if shape == 'RECTANGLE':
    Rectangle = Rectangle()
    print ("Rectangle Area is", Rectangle.getArea())
if shape == 'TRAPEZOID':
    Trapezoid = Trapezoid()
    print ("Trapezoid Area is", Trapezoid.getArea())
```

Here is the error I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/ChesTheGoat/work/code-check/area_calc.py", line 49, in <module>
    Trapezoid = Trapezoid()
TypeError: __init__() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'height', 'base', and 'base2'
```

If anyone can help me understand my mistake and help me out that would be amazing, thanks in advance!

Comment: `Trapezoid()` requires `height`, `base`, and `base2` arguments, but you didn't provide any of them.

Comment: Also, don't assign variables with the same names as the classes, you'll replace the classes.

Comment: You wrote `Trapezoid`'s `__init__` method to require a `height`, `base` and `base2` to be passed in. But you're calling `Trapezoid()` without giving any of them.

Answer (score 2):

Since your `__init__` methods prompt for the parameters of the shapes, you shouldn't list them as parameters to the method, and shouldn't pass them as arguments to the `super` method (it doesn't have them as parameters).

```
class Trapezoid(Calc):

     def __init__(self):
         super().__init__()
         self.base2 = int(input("Enter second base for Trapezoid:"))

     def getArea(self):
         return (self.base + self.base2) * self.height / 2
```